# Set a default value if no value is found in the API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a little app based on an assignment that shows a random set of countries and facts about them, including the countries they share borders with. If they don't share any borders the field is currently empty which I would like to change to "I'm an island", or something.

https://countries-display.herokuapp.com/

This should be easy, but I'm very new, and am not sure how to approach it. Any help or points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I tried initialising a default value:

```rb
class Country
  include HTTParty

  default_options.update(verify: false) # Turn off SSL verification
  base_uri 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/'

  format :json

  def initialize(countries = 'water')
    @countries = countries
  end

  def self.all
    @countries = get('/all')

    @countries.each do |country|
      country['borders'].map! do |country_code|
        @countries.find { |country| country['alpha3Code'] == country_code } ['name']
      end
      country['languages'].map! { |language| language['name'] }
      country['currencies'].map! { |currency| currency['name'] }
    end

    @countries
  end
end
```

Setting a default in active record:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.countries_to_display = 'water' if @countries_to_display.nil?
  end
end
```

I also tried implementing some if statements that were equally unsuccessful.

Solution:

```
@countries.each do |country|
    if country['borders'].empty?
        country['borders'] << "I'm an island"
    else country['borders'].map! do |country_code|
        @countries.find { |country| country['alpha3Code'] == country_code } ['name']
        end
    end
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `country['borders']` maps to the field that should contain `I'm an island`. I'm also assuming that you directly render the output of `Country.all`.

What you'll need to do is to add a check whether there are any borders and if there aren't write that string to the field instead of the list of bordering countries.

```rb
@countries.each do |country|
  if country['borders'].empty? 
    borders = "I'm an island"
  else 
    borders = country['borders'].map do |country_code|
                @countries.find { |country| country['alpha3Code'] == country_code }['name']
              end
 end
 country['borders'] = borders
 ...         
end
```

Note that we use `map` instead of `map!` here to not modify the existing collection. You may need to adjust your rendering logic, as `country['borders']` previously contained a list of countries and now contains a string.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I used the if statement to check if the value was empty and then add my string to the array so I wouldn't have to change the rendering logic.